# Pharo custom class is not indexable (smalltalk)

Tags: collections, smalltalk, pharo

I have the following code to create a collection as a member of a class:

```
 CustomClass new members:Set new; yourself.
```

next I ask for the size

```
custom members size.
```

which results in obviously 0, but when I insert a custom element in the set and I ask for the size it results in an error telling me my custom elements are not indexable.

```
custom members add: MyCustomElement new.
custom members size.  -> error
```

Why is this? How does one solve this issue in Smalltalk? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give us the definition of your `MyCustomElement`? Especially, have you implemented `#=` and `#hash`?

Comment: And could you please post the *exact* error description? E.g. which class is not indexable?

Comment: @Tobias what are #= and #hash ?

Comment: @MaxLeske I could solve it by doing the following: custom members asOrderedCollection size.

Comment: `#=` and `#hash` are methods that every object implements. If you override `#=` you usually have to also override `#hash` because of how hash based collections work. `#size` on hashed collections may use `#hash` for the lookup. That's why Tobias asked about their implementation. It would be helpful if you could still provide the information we asked for because what you describe should not happen in such a simple case.

Comment: What's the text of the error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you exhibit should not trigger the error.
But it's possible that you were bitten by the #add: message.

The #add: message returns the added element, this way you can chain additions like:

```
collection2 add: (collection1 add: element).
```

This also work with #at:put:

```
collection2 at: j put: (collection1 at: i put: k).
```

is much like

```
c2[ j ] = c1[ i ] = k;
```

Though, if you write something like:

```
| s e |
e := MyCustomElement new.
s := (Set new) add: e.
^s size
```

then the variable s will point to the same object than e, an instance of MyCustomElement, and not to the freshly created Set.

Above example thus send the message #size to an instance of MyCustomElement, and this sound very much like the error you described: this may trigger an error because the instances of this class are not indexable.

You can alternatively write:

```
(s := Set new) add: e.
```

or use a cascade that ends by sending #yourself to the Set, effectively returning the set itself:

```
s := (Set new) add: e; yourself.
```